# Are One Drive and Office 365 Sharepoint implementations with the desktop versions of Microsoft Office WOPI implementations or OAuth 2.0 ones?

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office, office365, onedrive, ms-wopi

How are the desktop versions of Microsoft Office 2016 products able to retrieve documents from and save documents back to One Drive when they (the desktop versions of Office 2016) are not [WOPI (Web Application Open Platform Interface)](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) clients?

I suspect that the desktop Office and One Drive integration looks more like an OAuth 2.0 implementation rather than a WOPI one.

I'd love to hear how that works, and especially would love to have it be confirmed whether or not the desktop versions of Office are WOPI clients (looks like they aren't because WOPI is for Web based applications).

Also, does Microsoft have any future plans to have desktop versions integrate with custom, third-party cloud storage providers? In other words, to make something like WOPI but for desktop clients like Office 2016? DOPI (Desktop ...) perhaps? :-)

Answer (score 0):

- Desktop versions of Office are not WOPI clients.
- Office <-> Sharepoint is WebDAV
- Office <-> OneDrive is not a real integration. It just uses OneDrive's file based synchronization.
- More detailed observations can be found in my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46245193/1332034)
- Not sure about the future plans of Microsoft but you can certainly create integrations with desktop versions of Office by implementing the WebDAV protocol. There are many examples and [paid SDKs](https://www.webdavsystem.com/) on the internet that'll save you from writing boilerplate code.