# Is Dropbox a WOPI Host? Is the Dropbox integration also available with the desktop version of Microsoft Office applications?

Tags: oauth-2.0, ms-office, office365, dropbox, ms-wopi

I believe Office and Dropbox integration is only for Office Online and not for the desktop versions of Office. I looked up the **File -> Open** menu in the Winword.exe 2016 and didn't see a way to add any other *place* other than One Drive and Office 365 SharePoint.

This leads me to believe that the One Drive and Sharepoint integration with the desktop versions are perhaps OAuth 2.0 implementations. And the Office Online and Dropbox integration is a WOPI one, Dropbox being the WOPI host?

Could you please confirm?

Answer (score 1):

- [Office Online integration <-> Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/help/files-folders/edit-microsoft-office-documents) is 100% WOPI and Dropbox is WOPI host
- Office 2016 <-> Sharepoint looks like WebDAV, looking at the HTTP headers (e.g. `Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD, MKCOL, PUT, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, DELETE, MOVE, COPY, GETLIB, LOCK, UNLOCK`)
- Office 2016 <-> OneDrive - doesn't look like an integration at all. Word just shows folders from the filesystem and the synchronization is facilitated by the OneDrive app itself. I've concluded that from the fact that Word only sees folders that are enabled for sync in the OneDrive app => it doesn't really communicate with the OneDrive online service to get the full list.